# Apply chown -R on subdirectories only and limit the deepness of the recursion

Tags: bash

I'm trying to change the owner of a directory and its sub-directories without changing the owner of the files. I know that `chown -hR $owner $Folder0` changes the owner of `Folder0` and its sub-files including directories. Is there a specific option of `chown` to do so? If not, I would like to limit the 'recursion' of `chown -hR` in order to make the change for the `Folder0`, `Folder1`, `Folder2`, and `Folder3`, ingnoring the subfiles (files and directories of `Folder3`. Is it possible to do something like `chown -hR -<magic option> 3 $owner $Folder0` instead of doing

```
chown $owner $Folder0
chown $owner "$Folder0/Folder1"
chown $owner "$Folder0/Folder1/Folder2"
chown $owner "$Folder0/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, there's `chown $Folder0{,/*{,/*{,/*}}}` or `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -exec chown $owner {} \;
```

This recursively lists folders for 3 levels from current directory, and for each match, runs chown

Comment: Using `+` instead of `\;` will drastically speed up the command.